# Unmute button for responsive embedded vimeo video

Tags: html, button, vimeo-player

I have used the vimeo generated code to embed my video in a wix website (using their HTML component tool). I've tweaked the code so it autoplays when the page loads, and it is responsive on resizing the browser window (plus full width on the webpage). The code used is:

```
<div style="padding:42.6% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/558081433?autoplay=1&muted=1&loop=1&autopause=0" 
frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen 

style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="Anthemic Piano">
</iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

I saw someone use some neat code to add an unmute button to their video, but the code generates a very small video area on the website, rather than the full width, responsive version I'm trying to get. Here is the code they used:

```
<button onclick="unmute()">
    UNMUTE
</button>
<div id="vimeo-player1"> </div>
<script>
    var options = {
        id: 194500280,
        background: true
    };
    var vid1 = new Vimeo.Player('vimeo-player1', options);
</script>
<script>
    function unmute() {
        vid1.setVolume(1);
    };  
</script>
```

I tried adding in

```
width: 100%
```

to the `var options = {}` part of the code, but this doesn't work to make it responsive/full width.

I'd be incredibly grateful if someone was able to help amalgamate my original code, with the unmute button code so I can finally get it working. Thank you so much for your help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the CSS width for container and iframe must help. The code below shows the video in full-width and UNMUTE button works as expected.

```
<style>
.container { 
height:95%;
width:100%;  
}
.container iframe{  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

</style>

<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="vimeo-player1"> </div>
<button onclick="unmute()">
    UNMUTE
</button>

<script>
    var options = {
        id: 558081433,
        background: true,
        muted:1,
        loop:1
        
    };
    var vid1 = new Vimeo.Player('vimeo-player1', options);
    vid1.play();
</script>
<script>
    function unmute() {
        vid1.setVolume(1);
    };  
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I am incredibly grateful indeed you took the time to write out this code for me, it works brilliantly on my website!! I'm so happy right now :)

If I could ask one more thing? I notice that clicking "unmute" does change the volume to full, however it also pauses the video. Is there a way to get it to purely unmute whilst the video still plays?

Comment: On my test id does not stop the video. Maybe the button is placed above the video in your screen. So, you need to decrease the height of the container. Please mark the answer to let others reach the solution quickly.

Comment: I tried using your code identically, and for me (in google chrome) clicking the "unmute" button still pauses the video. Changing the height of the container didn't affect this result unfortunately. Now I also have a new problem where the video fails to load/play in Safari. If you had any further thoughts on potential solutions, I'd be very grateful for your time.

Comment: Very strange. I testes exactly the same code on desktop with both Chrome and Edge, the video doesn't stop.

Comment: Yes, it does seem strange. Perhaps maybe because I'm on mac IOS 10.12.6? I'll keep trying!